# Connecting ArcGIS Online to PostgreSQL on Amazon Web Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, arcgis-online, amazon-web-services

I have some key data sets stored on PostgreSQL on an Amazon Web Server.
Is there any way, (direct or work around), that I can connect to this data in ArcGIS Online.

I can connect to it with ArcGIS Pro, but to then open that across in ArcGIS Online, I think it ends up packaging the dataset as it stands and effectively taking a copy.
If I then update/add to my PostgreSQL, the ArcGIS Online "version"(?) isn't updated without a manual refresh or reupload.

Are there any services that will facilitate such a connection?

Comment: The Esri "service" is called ArcGIS Server.  The Esri servers that run AGOL don't have access to your local database, but you can grant access to the local web server through which Server is managed. As this component has a significant licensing cost, you'll need to fall back a bit to do a cost-benefit analysis on whether realtime data change access is required, or a periodic upgrade solution in the AGOL=hosted database is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, when using ArcGIS Online, all the datasets must be copied into ArcGIS Online, thus creating a static copy of your data. The [publishing hosted layers section](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/publish-features.htm) of the help breaks this down. Simply, there is no way to host a service on ArcGIS Online that references data elsewhere (like your cloud PostgreSQL).

As @Vince points out in the comments, the technology here is ArcGIS Server. When publishing services to ArcGIS Server, you can reference the data from an enterprise geodatabase. Any edits/modifications made directly to the dataset in the database are available through the service.

If hosting your own GIS Server is not an option (meaning you only have ArcGIS Online), your only real course of action is to define a procedure to transfer data from PostgreSQL to the service, perhaps nightly.